# Find new blobs comparing two different binary images

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, computer-vision, object-tracking

I have two images taken on same sample at t=0 and t=t. There are few new blobs present in image taken at t. I need to find these new blobs (new blobs are the blobs which are present in new XY location at t=t). I am wondering if someone can help?

I tried OR,AND,XOR, reconstructions but the issue is the blobs which are same between two images are not exactly the same. Sometimes they might have size difference which makes the problem complicated.

Image at t=0
[image: Image at t=0]
Image at t=t
[image: Image at t=t]

Comment: You could either use contours to get the centroids or use connectedComponents to get the centroids. The just compare centeroids. If close enough in distance, then they are the same.  Alternately, do your diff processing (e.g. absdiff) and then use some morphology to clean up small changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using OR,AND,XOR, we may **sum** the two images.
Before summing the images, replace the 255 values with 100 (keeping the range of `uint8` [0, 255]).
In the summed image, there are going to be three values:

- `0` - Background
- `100` - Non-overlapping area
- `200` - Overlapping area

We may assume that pixels with value `100` that touches value `200` belongs to the same original blob.

For clearing the overlapping pixels (200) with the touching pixels (100 around them), we may use `cv2.floodFill`.

After clearing the overlapping pixels and the pixels around them, the pixels that are left (with value 100) are the new blobs.

Example for clearing the pixels using `cv2.floodFill`:

```
if sum_img[y, x] == 200:
    cv2.floodFill(sum_img, None, (x, y), 0, loDiff=100, upDiff=0)
```

Setting `loDiff=100` is used for filling pixels=100 (and pixels=200) with `0` value (`200-loDiff`=`100`, so the `100` is filled with zero).

For making the solution better, we may find contours (of pixels=200), and ignore the tiny contours.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input images as Grayscale.
img1 = cv2.imread('image1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('image2.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Replace 255 with 100 (we want the sum img1+img2 not to overflow)
img1[img1 >= 128] = 100
img2[img2 >= 128] = 100

# Sum two images - in the sum, the value of overlapping parts of blobs is going to be 200
sum_img = img1 + img2

cv2.floodFill(sum_img, None, (0, 0), 0, loDiff=0, upDiff=0)  # Remove the white frame.

cv2.imshow('sum_img before floodFill', sum_img)  # Show image for testing.

# Find pixels with value 200 (the overlapping blobs).
thesh = cv2.threshold(sum_img, 199, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Find contours (of overlapping blobs parts)
cnts = cv2.findContours(thesh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]


# Iterate contours and fill the overlapping part, and the non-zero pixels around it (i.e with value 100) with zero.
for c in cnts:
    area_tresh = 50
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > area_tresh:  # Ignore very tiny contours
        x, y = tuple(c[0, 0])  # Get coordinates of first pixel in the contour
        if sum_img[y, x] == 200:
            cv2.floodFill(sum_img, None, (x, y), 0, loDiff=100, upDiff=0)  # Setting loDiff=100 is set for filling pixels=100 (and pixels=200)

sum_img[sum_img == 200] = 0  # Remove the small remainders

#thesh = cv2.cvtColor(thesh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # Convert to BGR for testing (for drawing the contours)
#cv2.drawContours(thesh, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Draw contours for testing

# Show images for testing.
cv2.imshow('thesh', thesh)
cv2.imshow('sum_img after floodFill', sum_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Note:
We may dilate the images first, if the two blobs in proximity are considered to be the same blob (I don't no if a blob can "swim")

Output `sum_img` (after floodFill):
[image]

---

### Update:

The above solution finds the blobs that exist in image1 and not in image2 and blobs exist in image2 and not in image1.

In case we want to find only the blobs that are new in image2, and we also assume that blobs that are close in both images are the same one, we may add the following stages:

- Dilate `img1` and `img2` before summing (two close blobs are going to be overlapping).
- Remove the dilated pixels from `sum_img` at the end.
- Remove from `sum_img` all the blobs that exist only in `img1` (and not in `img2`).

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input images as Grayscale.
img1 = cv2.imread('image1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('image2.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Replace 255 with 100 (we want the sum img1+img2 not to overflow)
img1[img1 >= 128] = 100
img2[img2 >= 128] = 100

# Dilate both images - assume close blobs are the same blob (two blobs are considered overlapped even if they are close but not tuching).
dilated_img1 = cv2.dilate(img1, np.ones((11, 11), np.uint8))
dilated_img2 = cv2.dilate(img2, np.ones((11, 11), np.uint8))

# Sum two images - in the sum, the value of overlapping parts of blobs is going to be 200
sum_img = dilated_img1 + dilated_img2

cv2.floodFill(sum_img, None, (0, 0), 0, loDiff=0, upDiff=0)  # Remove the white frame.

#cv2.imshow('sum_img before floodFill', sum_img)  # Show image for testing.

# Find pixels with value 200 (the overlapping blobs).
thesh = cv2.threshold(sum_img, 199, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Find contours (of overlapping blobs parts)
cnts = cv2.findContours(thesh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]


# Iterate contours and fill the overlapping part, and the non-zero pixels around it (i.e with value 100) with zero.
for c in cnts:
    area_tresh = 0  # Optional
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > area_tresh:  # Ignore very tiny contours
        x, y = tuple(c[0, 0])  # Get coordinates of first pixel in the contour
        if sum_img[y, x] == 200:
            cv2.floodFill(sum_img, None, (x, y), 0, loDiff=100, upDiff=0)  # Setting loDiff=100 is set for filling pixels=100 (and pixels=200)

sum_img[sum_img == 200] = 0  # Remove the small remainders

sum_img[(img1 == 0) & (dilated_img1 == 100)] = 0  # Remove dilated pixels from dilated_img1
sum_img[(img2 == 0) & (dilated_img2 == 100)] = 0  # Remove dilated pixels from dilated_img2
sum_img[(img1 == 100) & (img2 == 0)] = 0  # Remove all the blobs that are only in first image (assume new blobs are "bored" only in image2)

# Visualization:
merged_img = cv2.merge((sum_img*2, img1*2, img2*2))

# The output image is img1, without the 
output_image = img1.copy()
output_image[sum_img == 100] = 0

# Show images for testing.
cv2.imshow('sum_img', sum_img)
cv2.imshow('merged_img', merged_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Output (`sum_img*2`):
[image]

Visualization for testing (`merged_img`):

- Green - exist only in `img1`
- Yellow - exist both in `img1` and `img2`
- Magenta - exist only in `img2`, and not too close to blob in `img1` (we are looking for the magenta blobs).

[image]